# Variable changes value without re-assignment

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that changes it's values by me updating the values from a different variable.

I'm trying to create my own object and was experimenting with some code I found online and I stumbled on this issue and can't wrap my head on how this happens.

Preparations:

```bsh
$a = "" | select First,Last #This just creates a custom object with two columns.
$b = @() #This is just an empty array to fill later on with the values of '$A'

$a.first = "Alpha"
$a.last = "Bravo"
$b += $a

$a.first = "Charlie"
$a.last = "Delta"
$b += $a
```

What is supposed to happen:

```
First   Last
-----   ----
Alpha   Bravo
Charlie Delta
```

But the actual results are:

```
First   Last
-----   ----
Charlie Delta
Charlie Delta
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: you are not adding COPIES of `$A` ... you are adding a reference to `$A`.[*grin*]  so when it changes the _references that point to it_ will also change. either use `.Clone()` or make new objects to add to your collection.

Comment: I wouldn't use clone personally, I'd make your own clone method within the object which constructs a new object from the values that are initialized in the old one and returns that new object. From what I've learned in my old computer science classes `.Clone()` doesn't necessarily make a deep copy... but doesn't necessarily make a shallow copy as well.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey in a custom object there is no .clone method.
Also can you please explain what you meant by make a new object? i'm asking because I used an custom object instead of an array to store the collection but it also stores the first object as a reference.

Comment: @Yeahish - i forgot that custom objects have no `.Copy()` or `.Clone()` methods. [*blush*] in that case, you will need to make a new one each time. since the `Select-Object` method is _SLOW_, you likely otta use the proper method = `[PSCustomObject]@{}`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: Agreed re `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }`, but note that you _can_ shallow-clone `[pscustomobject]`, namely via `.psobject.Copy()`.

Comment: @mklement0 - ooo! thanks for the reminder [*grin*] ... i had [once again] forgotten about the hidden `.PSObject` property.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, I'm quite new to this in depth powershell, can you please explain why the select-object method to create a custom object is slower then [pscustomobject], don't they both just do the same thing?

Comment: @Yeahish - the Select-Object method has a GREAT DEAL more code involved to allow it to handle many different use cases. plus, it requires one to send things across a pipeline ... which is always slower than the more direct methods. the `PSCO` technique is simpler since it is dedicated to making objects AND it does not require one to use the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) points out, you're adding *references* to the custom object (`[pscustomobject]`<sup>[1]</sup>) instance stored in `$a` to array `$b` (given that `[pscustomobject]` is a *reference type*), and you're updating the same custom object, so that you ended up with:

- 2 array elements that point to the very same object...
- ... whose property values are the last ones you assigned.

---

The most immediate fix is to create a *copy* of `$a` before assigning new property values, which can be done with `.psobject.Copy()`, which creates a - shallow - clone:

```
...
# Create a copy of $a to create the next array element.
$a = $a.psobject.Copy()

$a.first = "Charlie"
$a.last = "Delta"
$b += $a
```

Of course, you could avoid the problem and use custom-object *literals* (PSv3+) instead, which creates a new instance every time:

```
$b = @()

$b += [pscustomobject] @{ 
  first = "Alpha"
  last = "Bravo"
}

$b += [pscustomobject] @{ 
  first = "Charlie"
  last = "Delta"
}
```

As an aside: growing arrays with `+=` is inefficient, because a new array must be created behind the scenes every time; this may not be noticeable with only a few additions / iterations, but with a larger number it's better to use a list data type such as `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`:

```
$b = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

$b.Add([pscustomobject] @{ 
  first = "Alpha"
  last = "Bravo"
})

$b.Add([pscustomobject] @{ 
  first = "Charlie"
  last = "Delta"
})
```

---

#### [1] Custom objects in PowerShell:

`[pscustomobject]` (which is effectively the same as `[psobject]`) is PowerShell's "property bag" type that allows you to construct objects *ad hoc* without requiring a distinct .NET type declared ahead of time; from the perspective of .NET, a given custom object's type is always `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`, though the specific, dynamically attached properties can differ, by design.

`Select-Object` (`select`) too outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances, though they report a custom type name, via PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml), as their primary type name:

```
PS> ("" | select First,Last).pstypenames
Selected.System.String  # custom type name to reflect the type of the *input*
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject # the true type name
System.Object # the name of the base type
```

The above method of creating custom objects is *obsolete*, however, and PSv3+ supports literal `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntax for direct construction, which has the added advantages of being able to *initialize* the properties as part of the same statement and being *faster* than `Select-Object` (and also `New-Object`):

```
# PSv3+ equivalent of the above 
# (except for the custom 'Selected.System.String' type name),
# allowing you to also initialize the properties.
[pscustomobject] @{
   First = $null  
   Last = $null 
}
```

<sup>Note: In PSv2 you could use `New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{ ... }` to similar effect, but the order in which the properties are attached will typically not reflect the definition order.</sup>

Note that you can always instantiate regular .NET types in PowerShell as well, with the [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) cmdlet or, in PSv5+, alternatively with syntax `[<type>]::new([...])`.
You use the same methods to instantiate [PSv5+ custom classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) declared with the `class` keyword.