# Custom display in Format-Table

Tags: powershell

## Example class

Here's a simple class:

```
class ETF
{
    $Symbol
    [decimal]$Assets
}
```

Let's make a few instances:

```
$ls = (
    (New-Object ETF -Property @{ Symbol = 'ICLN'; Assets = 123456789 }),
    (New-Object ETF -Property @{ Symbol = 'FAN';  Assets = 234567890 }),
    (New-Object ETF -Property @{ Symbol = 'TAN';  Assets = 345678901 })
)
```

## Format-Table

Display the objects in a table:

```
$ls | Format-Table
```

```
Symbol    Assets
------    ------
ICLN   123456789
FAN    234567890
TAN    345678901
```

## Display Assets as currency

I'd like to display the `Assets` property as a currency value. Here's one way to do that:

```
$ls | Format-Table Symbol, @{ Label = 'Assets'; Expression = { '{0:C0}' -f $_.Assets } }
```

```
Symbol Assets      
------ ------      
ICLN   $123,456,789
FAN    $234,567,890
TAN    $345,678,901
```

## format-etf-table

That's quite verbose for interactive use.

One way to deal with this is to define a function for displaying ETFs in a table:

```
function format-etf-table ()
{
    @($input) | Format-Table Symbol, @{ Label = 'Assets'; Expression = { '{0:C0}' -f $_.Assets } }
}
```

```
$ls | format-etf-table
```

The downside to a specialized function like `format-etf-table` is that we lose the flexibility of `Format-Table`. E.g. things like selecting which properties to display.

## Types.ps1xml

I know that [Types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.2) can be used to customize the display of data and can perhaps be used in a case like this.

However, this approach seems to require having the user add a `ps1xml` file to thier `$PSHOME` directory. This seems a little heavy handed.

## Question

What's the recommended approach changing the default display of data in a table?

Do most people simply use `ps1xml` files?

Is there a way to achieve the effect of `ps1xml` files without installing them locally?

Is creating specialized formatting functions like `format-etf-table` what is most often done?

Are there other recommended approaches I haven't listed here?

Comment: In short: As of PowerShell 7.2.x, unfortunately, there is no _API_-based way to define custom formatting, so `.format.ps1xml` _files_ must be used - see the conceptual [about_Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) help topic (note that this is separate from custom _type_ modifications, as described in the conceptual [about_Types.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml) help topic, which _do_ have APIs).

Comment: However, you can construct such files _on demand_ in a session - but that is nontrivial - a bare-bones example is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526714/45375).

Comment: As an aside: I'd name your custom function `Format-EtfTable` - better not to use `-` twice in a command name.

Comment: As for what is most often done: For custom types emitted by commands that ship as part of _modules_, these modules typically come with their own `.format.ps1xml` files. Personally, I've rarely seen custom formatting functions. The inherent limitation of a function is that it must be applied _explicitly_ and, when you do, the output is no longer usable _as data_.